# Android: Get view reference to ActionBar navigation?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Currently, I need to access parts of the ActionBar in order to attach contextual help bubbles in appropriate locations. That seems fairly simple for Menu Items as menuItem.getActionView is available.

However, I'm not sure how to get similar access to the navigation list in the ActionBar. Instead of including items in the menu xml file, the navigation options and listeners are added like this:

```
getActivity().getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
getActivity().getActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(mNavigationListAdapter, this);
```

With Menu Items, the following works:

```
MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.my_nifty_menu_item);
View viewToAttachHelpBubbleTo = menuItem.getActionView();
```

How can I get a similar view reference to the navigation menu used in the ActionBar?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to store the view in the Adapter and then pull it from there.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Stuff happens...
    mLastParentView = parent;
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Stuff happens...
    mLastParentView = parent;
}

public View getLastParentView() {
    return mLastParentView;
}
```

and then after

```
getActivity().getActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(mNavigationListAdapter, this);
```

it is possible to just request the view for the navigation list from the adapter with getLastParentView()